# Find matching word and apply styles using renderer2

Tags: angular

I wanted to highlight a specific word in a string.
For Example `Hello Welcome! Click here for more details` in this string I wanted to highlight `Hello Welcome` .

Point to be noted : Highlight text is dynamic,  it keeps changing.

So How to find the `highlightText` and apply styles to it using angular renderer ?

Please suggested other possible solutions ?

**My HTML**

```
<p #test>Hello Welcome! Click here for more details</p>
```

**My code**

Below code dosen't work .

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('test') test: ElementRef;

  higlightText= 'Hello Welcome';

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  let text = this.test.nativeElement.innerHTML;
  let a = text.search(this.higlightText);
  this.renderer.setStyle(a,'font-weight','bold');
  }
}
```

**Link to Project:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer2-example-2-vtbhfq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Continuing what you've started : change `ngAfterViewInit` to :

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.renderer.setProperty(this.test.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', this.test.nativeElement.innerHTML.replace(this.higlightText,`<b>${this.higlightText}</b>`));
   }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer2-example-2-yweqw1?file=src/app/app.component.ts